# Javascript, URL parsing, string manipulation, navigation

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, string, navigation

Below is the script for a vertical navigation menu I have created in HTML/CSS/Javascript. You will notice the navigation menus are creating using lists (ul & li's)...

My question is this...

I want each link to be bold and display an » in-front of it when it is on that page.

With Javascript, how could I go about this? Each of the pages have a folder very similar to the link (for example, Sub-Item 1 would have a path of sitename.com/path/sub-item-1)...

I assume I can somehow grab the URL (which I already have done in the code), grab the string from the link somehow... and then reinsert the string,  but add a  and » to it.

EDIT: I SHOULD MENTION... This navigation is an include that plugs into all of my pages, therefore, adding the bold and » by hand on each document is not a feasible solution for this question.

Thanks for your help!

```
    <!-- Left Navigation starts here -->
            <!-- if IE -->
            <div id="IE_nav">
            <!-- endif IE -->
            <div id="left_nav">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li id="nav_1" class="nav_button">NAV ITEM 1</li></a>
                                <li class="sub_nav_box" id="sub-nav-1" style="display: none;">
                                    <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                    <a href="#"><li id="nav_2" class="nav_button">NAV 2</li></a>
                                <li class="sub_nav_box"  id="sub-nav-2" style="display: none;">     
                                    <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                    </ul>
            </div></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

    var URL = window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;

    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');

if (pathArray[2] == "nav_1")
 {
  document.getElementById("#").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('#').className = 'nav_selected';
 } 

if (pathArray[2] == "nav_2")
{
  document.getElementById("#").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('#').className = 'nav_selected';
}
</script>
```

You can essentially ignore what I have so far (as it works how I need it to), but how can I put a » infront of the Sub-Item links and make them bold... Using javascript.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you have another page in each folder. You probably have another file for each page too.
So you can add a class to the particular navigation item by hand in each file in each folder?

Assuming your not using PHP or something else to "include" pages in your main layout/index.

**When you ARE using something to include (in this case the navigation itself):**

You can split the URL by slashes `/`.
Like in your script right there, but there are some error's in there.
Here something better:

URL: `http://site.ext/path/sub-item-1/`

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.split('/');
url = url[4];

/*
4 because:
0 = http:
1 = <nothing between the two slashes>
2 = site.ext
3 = path
4 = sub-item-1/
*/

document.getElementById(url).className = 'active';
```

**Say you are using PHP:**

You can add a snippet of PHP to each navigation item and echo the class in there.
Then you will never have problems with JavaScript on the client-side.

```
<li<?php echo ($_GET['page'] == 'sub-item-1' ? ' class="active"' : ''); ?>>Sub Item 1</li>
```

**For making the text bold and adding `»`:**

You'll have to do this with CSS:

```
li.active {
    font-weight: bold;
}
li.active:before {
    content: "&raquo;&nbsp;";
}
```

Comment: I am using the navigation as an include for every page... therefore I do not have to keep changing it for every page. Too tedious.

Comment: That was not mentioned in your question ;-) I'll change my answer.

Comment: Why are you a bad ass? Thanks! I will give it a shot.

Comment: Any thoughts on adding the bold and &raquo;?

Comment: Any thoughts if I am not using PHP? I know, patience is a virtue.

Comment: Because your new, you maybe want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask